# How to get image URL from parameters in api and display it into Imageview

Tags: android, web-services, api, image-loading

I am working on a Social networking application in which I have to get user's details  from the server. I am getting user's Profile image url in parameter but I am having problem in getting image and displaying it, because every time it is showing only image url in Imageview.

this is my api feed:-

```
{"post_id":"559",
    "userid":"11",
    "content":"\u0908\u092e\u093e\u0928\u0926\u093e\u0930\u0940 \u090f\u0915 \u092c\u094b\u0939\u094b\u0924 \u092e\u0939\u0902\u0917\u0940 \u091a\u0940\u095b \u0939\u0948.... \u0917\u093f\u0930\u0947 \u0939\u0941\u090f \u0932\u094b\u0917\u094b \u0938\u0947 \u0909\u0938\u0915\u0940 \u0909\u092e\u094d\u092e\u0940\u0926 \u0928\u0939\u0940\u0902 \u0915\u0930\u0928\u0940 \u091a\u093e\u0939\u093f\u090f..",
    "favorite_count":"1",
    "reply_count":"2",
    "repost_count":"0",
    "post_location":"",
    "created_date":"2015-05-29 12:04:28",
    "name":"devraj singh","user_image":"http:\/\/sabakuch.com\/public\/images_upload\/avatars\/ozone\/11_30_11149322_10205781000956557_74437511307260696_n.jpg",
    "post_images":null,
    "gender":"1"}
```

here is my adapter class where I am getting the details.

```
    public class OzoneAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<Ozone_Beans> feedList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Activity activity;

    Context context;
    ImageLoader imageloader;



    public OzoneAdapter(ArrayList<Ozone_Beans> feedList, Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
        this.feedList = feedList;
        this.activity = activity;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater )activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageloader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(activity));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        return feedList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return feedList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null)
            //convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ozone_item, null);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ozone_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tvDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ozone_name);
        holder.tvContent = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ozone_content);
        holder.tvUser = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ozone_date);
        holder.image_user_image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ozone_user_image);
        holder.postImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ozone_post_image);



        holder.tvUser.setText(feedList.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvDate.setText(feedList.get(position).getCreated_date());
        holder.tvContent.setText(feedList.get(position).getContent());


        //imageloader.displayImage(feedList.get(position).getUser_image(), holder.image_user_image);
        //imageloader.displayImage(feedList.get(position).getUser_image(), holder.image_user_image);
        //holder.image_user_image.setImageURI(feedList.get(position).getUser_image());
    //  imageloader.displayImage(feedList.get(position).getTweet_images(), holder.postImage);

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image_user_image;
        public ImageView postImage;
        TextView tvContent , tvUser, tvDate;
    }

}
```

Comment: you want to fetch image from url u are getting in ur api response??

Comment: @Clairvoyant I want to display that image in layout but everytime it shows only url in layout in Imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this one try to implement in you code

```
 class Holder {
    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;
    ImageView iv1, iv2;

    public Holder(View v) {
        tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvCouponDeal);
        iv1 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        iv2 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return categoryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View dataRow = convertView;
        Holder holder = null;
        if (dataRow == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            dataRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_items_cell, parent, false);
            holder = new Holder(dataRow);
            dataRow.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) dataRow.getTag();
        }
        holder.tv1.setText(categoryList.get(position).getMerchantName());
        holder.tv2.setText(categoryList.get(position).getVoucherOfferlogo());
        holder.tv3.setText(categoryList.get(position).getOffertype());
        if(categoryList.get(position).getIsexclusive().equals("1"))
            holder.iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_selected);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(categoryList.get(position).getMerchantStanderedimage(), holder.iv1, options, animateFirstListener);
        return dataRow;
    }
}
private static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

    static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        if (loadedImage != null) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
            boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
            if (firstDisplay) {
displayedImages.add(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `NetworkImageView` of `Volley` library instead of `ImageView` that allows you to `setImageUrl`. `ImageLoader` associated with with it cache images downloaded for any `URL` and can be reused. Get more info on its [image cache](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/google-io-2013-volley-image-cache-tutorial). You could find decent tutorial [here](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/android-volley-tutorial/) and [here](http://cypressnorth.com/mobile-application-development/setting-android-google-volley-imageloader-networkimageview/). It should make your `ListView` images load correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to loading images from URL's, a good approach would be to use a Library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) (by square), it handles the downloading and caching pretty well, it's well documented and maintained, and the invocation is pretty easy, so it will save you time and aggro, e.g:

```
Picasso.with(context).
                    load(url).
                    fit().
                    transform(trans). // if you want any transformations..
                    centerCrop().
                    error(R.drawable.error_avatar). // in case of error
                    into(myImageView);
```

Another option is Fresco (by a facebook developer), but I have less first hand experience with that one.

Hope this Helps.